# How can I use Pusher Laravel Echo with SharedWorkers?

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, echo, pusher

I'm trying to keep only one connection active per user who open multiple tabs on my application that uses Pusher with Laravel Echo, I was able to get it working on a test project by following the article and the example project below.

https://blog.pusher.com/reduce-websocket-connections-with-shared-workers/
https://github.com/pusher-community/pusher-with-shared-workers

But I'm having a hard time trying to adapt it to work with my Laravel project, how should I do that?

Here is the configuration I have added to my `bootstrap.js` file

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    encrypted: true
});

$.getJSON( "/heartbeat", function( json ) {

    window.Echo.channel('user.' + json.user_id).listen('NotifyUser', e => {
        displayModal(e.msg);
        console.log('User with an id of ' + e.id + ' has been notified.');
        console.log(e);
        // Relay the message on to each client
        clients.forEach(function(client){
          client.postMessage(data);
        });
    });

});

self.addEventListener("connect", function(evt){

  // Add the port to the list of connected clients
  var port = evt.ports[0];
  clients.push(port);

  // Start the worker.
  port.start();
});
```

It's working but not the way I want, it's creating a new connection for each opened tab.

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: @Aaron3219, no errors at all.

Comment: You also ran `npm install` and `npm run dev`? I just want to make sure that those basics are set.

Comment: I just don't know how to achieve the same result using the Laravel method.

Comment: Yes, I always do after I edit my `bootstrap.js`.

Comment: Okay thank you. I will have a look at it. Do you have a repository or something, so I can look at the whole project?

Comment: No, I don't have any public repository. All I wanted was to implement the method from the article in Laravel echo.

Comment: The pusher connection is established in `node_modules/laravel-echo/dist/echo.js`. You will have to rewrite the `Pusher` parts and some of the `Echo` parts in this file to  use a `Shared web worker`. The question is: Do you really want to do this? You will have to spend hours to figure out the structures. Furthermore, it is a rather new technologies and not supported in all browsers (https://caniuse.com/). There might be some packages published in the future that implement a `Shared worker` in `Laravel Echo`. At the end you have to decide if you want to choose Pusher or an alternative.

Comment: Take a look at "https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/". It is a websocket package and easy to configure/implement. It also supports Laravel Echo and is (of course) completely free. Yes, it has downsides because websockets hosted on your own server need resources (not really that much tbh), but it is for free! Pusher is great, but not everything.

Comment: did you manage to get it working?

Answer (score 2):

As specified in the link you provided yourself: https://blog.pusher.com/reduce-websocket-connections-with-shared-workers/ , you need to import a specific version of pusher to use worker: `pusher.worker.js`.

So, go here: https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js/tree/master/dist/worker

and download the `pusher.worker.min.js` . Put it in the same directory as your `boostrap.js` and require it. Instead of:

```
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
```

use

```
importScripts("pusher.worker.min.js");
```

Comment: I tried replacing `import pusherClient from "pusher-js"` with `window.importScripts("pusher-js/dist/worker/pusher.worker.min");`, but I'm getting this error in the browser: `TypeError: window.importScripts is not a function`